# How can I compile OpenSplice 5.5.1 Community Edition with VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, opensplice

How can I compile OpenSplice 5.5.1 Community Edition with VS2012? I always get compile errors that Windows.h is not found. I tried to add / modify the build scripts that they start recognizing my VS2012 version, but I failed. Does anybody have working build-scripts and can describe me what to do?

Regards
Tobias

Answer (score 0):

With some help from here: http://forums.opensplice.org/index.php?/topic/2255-building-opensplice-551-on-vs2010-vs2012/ I managed to compile. Some make-files need to be adapted and the parsing of the cl.exe version needed to be changed.

I hope the community edition 6.3 that comes out in July will compile directly out of the box.